# Cannot find module 'require'

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mean-stack

**this is the error below**

> E:\freelancer-work-backup\scraping>node index.js
> [Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJSvl.jpg)

```
$ node index
module.js:341
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'require'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\freelancer-work-backup\scraping\index.js:1:83)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:447:10)
```

Code in index.js:

```
var request = require('require'),
    cheerio = require('cheerio');
var url = 'grocermax.com/catalogsearch/result/…';
request(url, function(err, resp, body) {
    if (!err && resp.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(body);
    } else {
        console.log("Failed");
    }
});
```

Comment: Dis you did `require("require")` somewhere in the code?

Comment: can you show your `app.js` code?

Comment: **This is the code in index.js**    >  `    var request  =  require('require'),
        cheerio  = require('cheerio');

    var url = 'https://grocermax.com/catalogsearch/result/?cat=&order=name&q=britannia';

    request(url,function(err,resp,body){ 
 
 if(!err && resp.statusCode == 200){
  
  console.log(body); 
  
 }else{
  console.log("Failed");
 }
 
});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the code to `var request = require('request')`